# Have a simple program to manage my spreadsheets but pulling data taking too long

Tags: python, gspread

Ok so I am using gspread to pull data on google spreadsheets but for what I am doing I need to pull data from long columns. Anyway the data that is being pulled doesn't need to be there until half way through the program. Is there a way to pull that data at the beginning while the first half of the program is running?

-As it runs right now it looks up some individual values ~5 seconds
-then it pulls the data from the columns and takes ~4-15 seconds (it varies) but it isn't doing ANYTHING but pulling the data so it just sits there.
-then it continues and does the rest of the calculations which take ~1 second.

I feel like this is inefficient and since it deals with minutes I worry that it might start to interfere with the way it runs when the columns get especially long...

Here is the paste bin for the code with my information removed http://pastebin.com/Wf5bfmZ0

Comment: Can you show us the code related to downloading the spreadsheets? Perhaps there is a way to optimize the call so that downloading won't take so long.

Comment: I edited it with the paste bin.

Comment: the row_count function in gspread would also really come in handy for what I am doing but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work. If I did I wouldn't need to grab the entire list until the end of the day. I could just use that value -1 to pull the specific numbers I need for the calculations.